# tkinter code animates some gifs but not all of them

Tags: python, tkinter, gif

I am using the following code to animate gifs on tkinter.

```
class gif:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        fIndex = 0
        global frames
        frames = []
        global lastFrame
        while True:#infinite loop
            try:#executes following code if possible
                part = 'gif -index {}'.format(fIndex)#takes an index of a frame of gif
                frame = PhotoImage(file=filename,format=part)
                print(str(fIndex))
        #converts each frame to a PhotoImage
            except:#once the last frame is reached, this is executed
                lastFrame = fIndex - 1#last frame index saved
                break #while loop ends
            frames.append(frame) #photoimage of frame added to list
            fIndex += 1 #index incremented


    def animate(self,fNumber):#function to animate gif
        if fNumber > lastFrame: #if the last frame is reached,
            fNumber = 0 #index changed to 0 so it plays again
        canvas.create_image(700,350,image=frames[fNumber],anchor=CENTER) 
        master.after(20,self.animate,fNumber+1)#each frame played with
    #20 milliseconds in between

matr1x = gif('spinningmatrix.gif')
matr1x.animate(0)
```

this works for some of my gifs but not all of them. For the ones that don't work, when I print fIndex it only displays 0 and 1 and only the first frame is displayed on the GUI. the ones that do work have more indexes displayed. just wondering why some don't work and why it only gives me 0 and 1 as the indexes. any help would be appreciated.
edit: I split the gifs into frames online and for 2 of the gifs that work properly, my program gives the correct number of frames. for one that works but is a bit off, the program says 3 frames but online says 20. for the other 2 that don't work at all, the number of frames differ very much online.

Comment: It sounds like some of the gifs don't have multiple frames, and/or all of the frames are the same.

Comment: ***"canvas.create_image(..."***: You are creating and stacking images over and over again. Read up on [Canvas.itemconfigure-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfigure-method)